# Why is a round robin distribution better for a skewed dataset?

Tags: azure-sql-data-warehouse

I have a skewed dataset, where most rows fall into the largest 10 values of my best candidate distribution key. My data is made up of two large tables, that only share two keys - my best candiate key, plus one other, but that one is null 80% of the time, so I have discounted it as an option.

Conventional wisdom says that if the data is skewed, I should use a round robin distribution. Looking at the explain plans produced by joins on the tables, I see my candidate column is the shuffle key for the shuffle move. This makes me question if I should change the distribution from round robin, to hash distributed, saving the time it takes to move data on every execution.

Is my logic correct? I feel like this is against the conventional wisdom when working with distributed sql. I don't expect any queries where this join isn't required, so that may be where others would see the benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round robin **always** entails data movement because of its nature, but it needn't be catastrophic for your performance.  The reason you use it for skewed data is because, when you distribute by hash, a unique hash is generated for each value and the rows distributed across the 60 distributions accordingly.  In  your example, most of your data would end up on one (or only a few) distribution(s) and you are therefore not taking advantage of the compute available to you.  Let's say you only have the opportunity of taking advantage of 20% of the compute resources available to you and the rest is idle.

The requirements for good hash columns are: they should not be updateable, not NULLable, should have large number of distinct values and even distribution.

Do you have an option to create a concatenated key from the others?  That could help create a more even distribution and would be useful as long as you used it in joins between the two tables.

Just some other advice, design for your key queries, use some of the other features available in SQL DW like the right DWU, resource classes, non-clustered indexes, auto-statistics.  Please also note that [generation 2 of SQL DW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/upgrade-to-latest-generation) is now available.

HTH

Comment: That makes sense, although I'm still unsure on what the benefit of round robin and shuffle move is, over hash distribution. Where both the shuffle key and distribution key are the same.

Comment: Round Robin will distribute your data evenly across all 60 nodes.  The shuffle key will be whatever you are joining on.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what shuffle does, but doesn't shuffle re-distribute the data based on the key? or is there some processing that happens before that that can take advantage of the better distribution from RR

Comment: SHUFFLE_MOVE simply redistributes a distributed table.  From your description, your data is in a round robin distribution in two tables.  The data will be distributed evenly but randomly, ie it will be different for the two tables.  When you join those two tables, you join on a key.  In order to service that join for your two tables, data movement service (DMS) will re-distribute the data for the same keys in both tables to the same distributions in order to service your join.  Did you consider my option of a concatenated key?

Comment: that makes sense! I think you are right that a concatenated key might be the best option, I'm looking into it

Comment: Strangely, the more skewed dataset runs marginally quicker than when using a copy of the table with the concatenated key. My suspicion is that it's the inclusion of the new column in the join/group by is causing more work than is saved. I'm feeling my data is just the wrong shape for Azure data warehouse.